# problems with dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, casting, shared-ptr

I have this snippet of the code:

```
void addLineRelative(LineNumber number, LineNumber relativeNumber) {
            list<shared_ptr<Line> >::iterator i;
            findLine(i, number);
            if(i == listOfLines.end()){
                throw "LineDoesNotExist";
            }
    
   line 15  if(dynamic_cast<shared_ptr<FamilyLine> >(*i)){
                cout << "Family Line";
            } else {
                throw "Not A Family Line";
            }
        }
```

I have class Line and derived from it FamilyLine and RegularLine, so I want find FamilyLine

my program fails on the line 15, I receive an error

```
cannot dynamic_cast target is not pointer or reference
```

can somebody please help, thanks in advance

#### edited

I tried this one:

```
shared_ptr<FamilyLine> ptr(dynamic_cast<shared_ptr<FamilyLine> >(*i));
if(ptr){
    //do stuff
}
```

the same error

## edited

```
void addLineRelative(LineNumber number, LineNumber relativeNumber) {
        list<shared_ptr<Line> >::iterator i;
        findLine(i, number);
        if(i == listOfLines.end()){
            throw "LineDoesNotExist";
        }

        shared_ptr<FamilyLine> ptr(dynamic_pointer_cast<FamilyLine>(*i));
        if (ptr){
            cout << "Family Line";
        } else {
            throw "Not A Family Line";
        }
    }
```

receive this error

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - `dynamic_pointer_cast' was not declared in this 
     scope
    - unused variable 'dynamic_pointer_cast'
    - expected primary-expression before '>' token
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shared_ptr` does not implicitly convert to a pointer - it is a class-type object - and `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast` and `const_cast` all operate on pointers only.

While you could use `dynamic_cast` on `shared_ptr<T>::get()`, its better to use `dynamic_pointer_cast<FamilyLine>()` instead as you might otherwise accidentally introduce double-`delete`s:

> **Returns:**
>    * When `dynamic_cast<T*>(r.get())` returns a nonzero value, a `shared_ptr<T>` object that stores a copy of it and shares ownership with r;
>    * Otherwise, an empty `shared_ptr<T>` object.
>   [...]
>   **Notes:**  the seemingly equivalent expression

```
shared_ptr<T>(dynamic_cast<T*>(r.get()))
```

> will eventually result in undefined behavior, attempting to delete the same object twice.

E.g.:

```
shared_ptr<FamilyLine> ptr(dynamic_pointer_cast<FamilyLine>(*i));
if (ptr) {
    // ... do stuff with ptr
}
```

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: dynamic_pointer_cast, where can I find it, my compiler doesn't know about it

Comment: @hello: What version are you using, TR1 et al (use `<memory>`) or boost (`<boost/pointer_cast.hpp>`)? *(Side-note: The owner of a post is always notified of comments, so the @user syntax isn't neccessary in this case)*

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: I don't know, I'm working on Eclipse Galileo and I use using namespace std;

Comment: Then you are probably using TR1 or C++0x features and `#include <memory>` should be sufficient.

Comment: Well, every C++ library worth its grain either has its types and functions in a namespace (like `std` for the standard library, `boost` for Boost, ...) or at least gives them a common prefix (`Q` for Qt). So as long as you don't have any using directives for `boost` anywhere but have them for `std`, the `shared_ptr` has to come from the standard library or an extension of it. This confusion is by the way a good argument against putting `using namespace foo;` everywhere.

Comment: I tried it, but it gives me an error about unused variable dynamic_pointer_cast, which namespace do I need?

Comment: @hello: Do you have `#include <memory>`? Do you use any special includes (i.e. besides `<memory>`) for `shared_ptr`?

Comment: yes, I did #include <memory>, yes I use #include "shared_ptr.h"

Comment: Aha, what is `shared_ptr.h`? Where does that come from?

Comment: there I have all difinitions and implementations of the shared_ptr, but it is working perfectly, I checked it

Comment: @hello: What is that, is that a custom implementation of `shared_ptr`? Or did you extract it from Boost? If its custom, its rather confusing - if you use `shared_ptr` in C++ people expect it to be either from TR1, the next C++ standard or Boost.

Comment: yes it is a custom implementation of shared_ptr, I received it  from lecturer, so it might work, can we return please a little bit: can I do something like this:
shared_ptr<FamilyLine> ptr(dynamic_cast<FamilyLine*>((*i).get()));

Comment: @hello: It might seem to work, but it has the problem that `ptr(x)` takes ownership of the instance `x` points to and thinks it has to `delete` the pointer it got which would lead to a double `delete` - so either your `shared_ptr` has a constructor that does not take ownership or you have to ask the lecturer how you are supposed to do this.

Comment: If it is similar to Boosts version and it has a version that allows `shared_ptr<FamilyLine> p(*i, dynamic_cast<FamilyLine*>(i->get()));` then `p` should share ownership with `*i`.